# How can I export a XenServer virtual machine with all its snapshots?

Tags: virtualization, xenserver, xen

Is there a way to export a virtual machine running on XenServer with all its past snapshots? I have tried to export a VM through XenCenter (right click on the machine and "Export..."). After importing it ("File > Import..."), all the past snapshots were gone.

There is a way to export single snapshots by selecting them individually, but then they become standalone VMs, and I would prefer to store the relationships between them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to export a VM and all its attachments as a single file.

It is possible to do delta exports (exporting just the difference between two snapshots):

```
xe vdi-export uuid=<current snapshot> base=<previous snapshot> filename=delta.vhd format=vhd
```

If you do this you can export a VM and all the snapshots much quicker and using less space than exporting all snapshots as full images. You will need to record somewhere the relationships of these delta exports as that data is not stored within the exports themselves.